# Line up a flex-element on the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="cart-info">
    <img src="./assets/images/conserve2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="product-info">
        <p>Peperoni sott'olio</p>
        <small>da <a href="#">Rivenditore</a></small>
        <br>
        <button id="btn-cart" class="btn bg-cart">Rimuovi</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the div looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLh1y.png
The The "Rimuovi" button should be aligned on the bottom of the div, so exactly on the same line as the image. Do you know how I can solve?
My css is:

```
.cart-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: where is your css? add that too.

Comment: Share an example on codepen

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cart-info {
  display: flex;
}

.product-info {
  display: Flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.product small {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-info">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-square-grunge-sign-260nw-1474408826.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="product-info">
    <div class="product">Peperoni sott'olio
      <small>da <a href="#">Rivenditore</a></small>
    </div>

    <br>
    <button id="btn-cart" class="btn bg-cart">Rimuovi</button>
  </div>
</div>
```